# Calculate sum of int inputs using a for statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, input, sum

I've just started (yesterday) learning how to code in C++ and I'm following Lippman's 'C++ Primer' book.

He gives us this code bit:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

{

    int sum = 0, value = 0;

    // read until end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read

    while (std::cin >> value)

        sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value

    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Works fine. Now, one of the exercises is to write my own version of a program that prints the sum of a set of integers read from cin. I'm trying to do that using a for statement. Right now I have this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int sum = 0;

    std::cout << "Please insert your values. When you want to terminate, insert the number 0." << std::endl;


    for(int val1; val1 != 0; std::cin >> val1)
        sum += val1;

    std::cout << "The sum of your inputs is " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

To avoid having to crtl + z to end the program, I'm trying to add a condition in which when the user inputs the number zero the program outputs the sum of all the inputs and terminates. For some reason, the sum I get is always wrong, i.e., I input 9 and 9 and the sum outputs 16.

In summarizing, I want the user to keep inputing numbers until he doesn't want to anymore (inputs the number zero), at which point the program calculates the sum of all former inputs and outputs the result.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It might be useful to use recursion here.

Comment: What OS/compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding val1 to the sum before it is initialized,

You can check that by printing what is the value of val1 that is added to the sum at each iteration:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int sum = 0;

    std::cout << "Please insert your values. When you want to terminate, insert the number 0." << std::endl;
    for ( int val1;  val1 != 0; std::cin >> val1 )  {
        std::cout << "Adding " << val1 << " to the sum" << std::endl;
        sum += val1;
    }
    std::cout << "The sum of your inputs is " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

You will see at the first iteration of the loop, before the user inputs any number, a value is added to the sum.
To understand why this is the case you can look at how you can translate your for loop in a equivalent while loop:

```
int val1 <initialization>
while (val1 != 0)  <condition>
    sum += val1;   <body>
    std::cin >> val1 <post-statement>
```

As you can see your initialization statement does not set a specific value for val1. That value is read in the body of the loop **before** the post-statement is executed.
This is true for any for loop:

```
for(initialization, condition, post-statement)
    body
```

A solution is to initialize val1 with the first number input from the user:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int sum = 0;

    std::cout << "Please insert your values. When you want to terminate, insert the number 0." << std::endl;
    int val1;
    for ( std::cin >> val1;  val1 != 0; std::cin >> val1 )  {
        std::cout << "Adding " << val1 << " to the sum" << std::endl;
        sum += val1;
    }
    std::cout << "The sum of your inputs is " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I thought that the only for statement that was executed was the third one, I thought the first two just initialized and checked, but coudln't handle orders like inputs.

So, with your code I ask for an input, check for different than zero, and if true advance to another input.

Why doesn't it result in input1, check, input2 and sum+= input2 ignoring input1? After all the for goes all the way to the end of the header before executing the body, right? And if it does, input1 would be ignored because before the body executes, input2 would have stored another value, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing the exact semantic of a for loop in C++
I will edit my answer!

Comment: I understand my mistake now. I was getting at the full expression as the loop, when in practice the actual loop excludes the initialization, as this is only executed once. Then goes to condition, body, afterthought, body, afterthought, body, afterthought, and so on until the condition is false. I was under the impression that the initialization was executed every single time. The book states this, but I misinterpreted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The for statement can look the following way

```
for ( int val1; std::cin >> val1 && val1 != 0; )
    sum += val1;
```

As for your for statement

```
for(int val1; val1 != 0; std::cin >> val1)
    sum += val1;
```

then first of all variable `val1` initially was not initialized so the loop is wrong. And you have to check whether operation `std::cin >> val1` was successfull.

Comment: Thank for answer. I'm trying to avoid relational operators (except for != because my condition needs it) as the book hasn't mentioned them yet, although I personally know them. I'm just trying to not put the cart in front of the horse.

I initialized the variable as you said and modified the code to this:

<code>for(int val1 = 1; val1 != 0; std::cin >> val1)
        sum += val1;

    std::cout << "The sum of your inputs is " << sum - 1 << std::endl;<code>

It's not really pretty, but gets the job done.

Comment: @NunoSimões In the last case the loop is also is wrong because the initial value of val1 equal to 1 will be added to the sum though it was not entered.

Comment: @NunoSimões Oh, I am sorry. I did not see that you subtract 1. However such an approach can confuse readers of the code.

Comment: @NunoSimões And in any case you do not check whether the input was successful.

Comment: Yes, I modified the "<< sum" to "sum - 1" because of that. The problem was not initializing the variable.

I know it's not pretty, but I'm trying to complicate things for myself by not using more advanced comparators than the ones already presented to me by the book, which makes it harder, but also more interesting for me.

I tried to find a way to do it by initializing val1 to zero to avoid having to "sum - 1", but I can't really do it if I want to terminate when the input is zero, right? It will always check the value and if it finds zero it terminates the for and goes to the next thing.

Comment: I thought the second part of the for statement was just for a check, I didn't know you could throw an order like std::cin in there and have it execute. I thought that only the third part and the body did that.

In my mind that checked whether there there was an input or not and if it was different than zero, but that it didn't actually ask for one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `while` loop, just extend the condition: `while ((std::cin >> value) && (0 != value))`.

It extracts an `int` out of `std::cin`, and if that was successful then checks if it was not `0`.

Comment: @Gernot1976 You can often "make" code work with either a `for`, `while` or `do` loop, but usually/often, one is better suited to the task than the others.  This case feels best with a `do` or `while` loop: _forcing_ someone to make a for-loop work seems the wrong approach to me.

Comment: It's just a way of trying to make things more interesting for me through challenges while learning. I know that in this case a while is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting strange answers is because you are using the variable `val1` before you initialize it. That is undefined behaviour.

[Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160326/calculate-sum-of-int-inputs-using-a-for-statement/34160421#34160421) will take care of that problem because `val1` will be properly initialized before it is added to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The variable val1 should be initialized, else it will hold garbage value.
You can rather use:

```
int val1;

std::cin >> val1;

for ( ;  val1 != 0; std::cin >> val1 )  {    
    sum += val1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer your question explicitly, I'd like to mention you can insert an `EOF` character manually by pressing `Ctrl+D`.  Inputting this `EOF` character is equivalent to "closing" `std::cin`, breaking you out of any loop that's depending on it.

Also, I recommend using (and learning about) some of the handy STL algorithms for your program instead of hard-coding the for-loop!

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    auto cin_iter = std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin};
    auto cin_end = std::istream_iterator<int>{};
    std::cout << "Sum is: " << std::accumulate(cin_iter, cin_end, 0) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7646eda9c9571384), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/), [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/).